# Volume of sphere in python

Tags: python, ipython

I can easily calculate the volume of a sphere in python using this code.

```
import math

radius = input("Enter Radius: ")
print("Radius: " + str(radius))

r = float(radius)

volume = 4.0/3.0 * math.pi * (r*r*r)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,2)))
```

Now my plan is to find the volume in n dimension. The equation I have derived to find the volume  and graphical changes of volume  is that [image]

I wanted to use  like this

```
import math

dimension = input("Enter dimension: ")
print("dimension: " + str(dimension))
n = float(dimension)
volume = math.pi^(n/2)/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,2)))
```

It's not working. Can you help me  finding the volume for different dimension with  getting the plot for the  volume of the sphere?

Comment: `volume = math.pi ** (n / 2) / math.gamma(n / 2 + 1)`.  IE `**` not `^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change:

```
volume = math.pi(n/2)^2/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
```

to:

```
volume = math.pi**(n/2)/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
```

**Complete code:**

```
import math

dimension = input("Enter dimension: ")
print("dimension: " + str(dimension))
n = float(dimension)
volume = math.pi**(n/2)/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,4)))
```

Input:

```
Enter dimension: 3
```

Output:

```
dimension: 3
Volume: 4.1888
```

*Additional:*

```
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
for dimension in range(100):
    n = float(dimension)
    volume = math.pi**(n/2)/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
    x.append(n)
    y.append(volume)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: can you include   the code  that  the volume of  different n at a time  from the graph. It would be easier to match with the  online resources?

Comment: The code for the n cases is in the additional. If my answer helps you mark it as correct please.

Comment: I can not check till I get the value of volume  for different n.

Comment: I do not understand you, could you explain me better please?

Comment: For example  n= 3, the volume would  be 4.1888.  How can i get  get numerical value of V as well in addition to the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand  your code  perfectly. I'm curious  if  there any way to  do the same thing   using Monte Carlo method?  I can ask another question separately if you say yes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `pow()` is what you need:

```
import math

dimension = input("Enter dimension: ")
print("dimension: " + str(dimension))
n = float(dimension)
volume = pow(math.pi,(n/2))/math.gamma(n/2 + 1)
print("Volume: " + str(round(volume,2)))
```

`pow(x,y)` Returns x to the power y.